# How to configure and execute multiple Tags for junit in Intellij in Run/Debug Configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, junit5

I have some junit5 tests in my project, I have used the **@Tag** annotations for some of the classes. I am successfully able to run those classes from Intellij via configuring the Run/Debug like below. This looks good when I use single type of tag eg. **suite-three**
[Image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AXfS.png)

The problem I am facing is, Now I want to run classes with two different tags at the same time, since I am executing the some tests Parallelly. Inorder to achieve this I have created an intermediate Bootstrap kind of class where I am using **@SelectClasses** annotations class to pass this 2 Test classes which I wish to execute like this
[Image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgIrl.png)
. So here when I configure the Tags from Intellij like below screenshot
[Image-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF0NK.png)

Notice I am sending two different tags, but Intellij doesnt executes the Test class and it keeps on giving me this message "No Tests Found".

Any help would be mighty helpful to me.

Comment: Hi, have you tried using the `&` between the tags?

Comment: Hi @OlgaKlisho thanks for the reply, meanwhile I was able to crack this by using | pipes for OR which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

We can use | pipes for running multiple classes together viz. `tag-1 | tag-2` this will run all the classes which are tagged with tag-1 OR tag-2. I am running this classes parallelly with JUnit5's new method with usage of `junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true`